# how to display in the console ‘Tuesday’,’Wednesday’,’Thursday’,’Friday’,‘Saturday’ ,’Sunday’ and ‘Monday’ if I enter ‘Monday’ in the prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to `display the entered day` in the prompt at the `last` after all days in the console as mentioned above in the question above. So far I have tried this logic but still the entered day is displaying at the `top` instead of at the `end`. If someone can please help me in rectifying my code

`JS`

```
const daysOfWeek = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
let currentDay = prompt("Enter day of week:");
while (!daysOfWeek.includes(currentDay)) {
  currentDay = prompt("Invalid day. Enter day of week:").toLowerCase();
}
let currentDayPassed = false;
const daysLeft = [];
for (let i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++) {
  if (daysOfWeek[i] === currentDay) {
    currentDayPassed = true;
  }
  if (currentDayPassed) {
    daysLeft.push(daysOfWeek[i]);
  }
}
console.log(daysLeft);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this quite simply like:

```js
let days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];

// You got this part right :-)
let selectedDay = prompt("Enter day of week:").toLowerCase();
while(!days.includes(selectedDay)){
    selectedDay = prompt("Invalid day. Enter day of week:").toLowerCase();
}

// Retrieve the index of the selected day.
const selectedDayIndex = days.indexOf(selectedDay);

// Crop that amount of elements from the start of the original array, and store
// the cropped elements inside of the croppedDays variable.
const croppedDays = days.splice(0, selectedDayIndex + 1);

// Add the cropped days to the end of the spliced array.
days = [...days, ...croppedDays];
console.log(days);
```

It might be worth reading up on the [`.splice()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method if you're not quite sure how it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Grover for the method and yes the documentation really helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using `indexOf` to find the index of the day in the array and then using that value to slice the array before and after the selected day:

```js
const daysOfWeek = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
let currentDay = prompt("Enter day of week:");
let dayNum = daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay);
while (dayNum < 0) {
  currentDay = prompt("Invalid day. Enter day of week:").toLowerCase();
  dayNum = daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay);
}

let daysLeft = daysOfWeek.slice(dayNum+1).concat(daysOfWeek.slice(0, dayNum+1))

console.log(daysLeft);
```

Comment: Thank you Nick for making me understand the logic it really helped to understand.